# Go ignores GOMAXPROCS

Tags: multithreading, go, goroutine

I'm trying to run a goroutine (go version go1.4.1 darwin/amd64) simultaneously with endless loop in main thread and I can't make it works. If I understood correctly go should schedule a goroutine to other threads if I specify GOMAXPROCS but it won't. Even if I write explicitly `LockOSThread()` in main I still can see no output. How to make go to run goroutine in separate os thread?

```
package main

import(
    "fmt"
    "time"
    "runtime"
)

func main() {
    runtime.GOMAXPROCS(runtime.NumCPU() * 8)

    go func() {
        for {
            time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
            fmt.Println("From routine")
        }
    }()

    for {}
}
```

Comment: I think that the problem here is that the new goroutine is not yet created (so it cannot be scheluded) when you enter for{} . The scheduler can only work then a goroutine is blocked or calls another function, so in a closed loop the scheduler cannot schedule. Add a time.Sleep(time.Millisecond) before the for{} and it will work.

Comment: @siritinga yes, it helps. Thank you. Please, make an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the new goroutine is not yet created (so it cannot be scheluded) when you enter `for{}`. The scheduler can only work then a goroutine is blocked or calls another function, so in a closed loop the scheduler cannot schedule.

Add a time.Sleep(time.Millisecond) before the `for{}` and it will work.

However, I don't know if you are doing this just for fun, but if you want to wait forever (or until the other gorounties are dead-locked or die) while the goroutines work, it is much better to use `select{}` that will block without wasting CPU cycles.

Comment: Better than `time.Sleep` would be [`runtime.Gosched`](https://golang.org/pkg/runtime/#Gosched).

Comment: I tried that, Dave, but it seems that in about 10% of the cases the scheduler will run main again before the goroutine is created (tested on Go1.4.2 and Raspberry Pi). Of course the best solution would be to use channels or WaitGroup to signal the main goroutine that the new one is alive.